# Can I replace values in SQL with regular expressions like in R or Python?

Tags: sql, replace

I am new to SQL and I want  to replace multiple valuse in columns and use nested replace statement which is not very comfortable to use.

```
replace(
    replace(
     replace(
      replace(
        replace(
         replace(
            replace(Event, 'HTTPS://LIVE', ''), 
                        'HTTPS://RU', ''), 
                                'HTTPS://SELECT', ''), 
                                    'HTTPS://SOUP', ''),
                                        'HTTPS://PRIVET', ''),
                                            '/EN', '')
```

Can I create a vector and filter a column based on this vector? Thanks

Comment: which version of SQL?  In MSSQL 2017 you can actually just write Python inline.

Comment: as I know it's an old version(not 2018), maybe I should update SQL on my computer to the newest one. Thank you

Comment: For sure, if you are comfortable with python or R you can just write legit code in SQL.  I'll answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty big example, but you can see how you can get Python running inline.  You'll need MSSQL 2017 at a minimum.  In addition you'll have to enable/install Python like this for SQL.  Note it installs its own version of Python and you can install packages and such.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-2017

There are a lot of tutorials on getting Python turned on so I won't go into those details, but here is some runnable code you can use as a starting point.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DATATABLE') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[DATATABLE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATATABLE](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VALUE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DATATABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DATATABLE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DATATABLE_VALUE]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [VALUE]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DATATABLE]
([VALUE])
VALUES
('apple'),
('orange'),
('pear')

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('usp_fruit') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_fruit
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_fruit
AS

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
#convert the data frame to a dict, then back to dataframe for output
import re
import pandas as pd
MyDict = dict(zip(MyInput.id, MyInput.value))
MyNewDict = {}
for key, value in MyDict.items():
    #upper case third character if it is a lower case p, for example
    value = re.sub("^(..)p(.*)", "\\1P\\2", value)
    MyNewDict[key] = "".join([value, " is a fruit"])

MyOutput = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(MyNewDict, orient="index", dtype=None)
MyOutput.index.name = "Keys"
MyOutput.reset_index(inplace=True)

#if you just want to do a simple regex in the dataframe:
#MyOutput = MyInput
#MyOutput = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
#MyOutput["value"].replace("ap{0,2}(le)", "where is \\1 fruit", inplace=True, regex=True)
',
@input_data_1_name = N'MyInput',
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT ID as id, VALUE as value FROM DATATABLE',
@output_data_1_name = N'MyOutput'
WITH RESULT SETS ((RESULTID INT, RESULTVALUE VARCHAR(50)))
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DATATABLE_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DATATABLE_TEMP
GO

CREATE TABLE #DATATABLE_TEMP (RESULTID INT, RESULTVALUE VARCHAR(50))
GO

INSERT INTO #DATATABLE_TEMP
EXEC usp_fruit
GO

SELECT RESULTID, RESULTVALUE FROM #DATATABLE_TEMP
```